# Create a form in WordPress that captures email of a user and sends automated response to user's email

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress as CMS, want to build a email capturing mechanism. The user keys in the email, post which autotrigger email goes to user's email ID with a white paper download link. How can it be done?

I was trying contact form 7 but the functionality does not work.

Comment: There are many plugins available one of wpforms try these steps
https://wpforms.com/how-to-send-a-pdf-attachment-in-a-form-notification-email/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.